# I want to list data from mysql table but I want to order it by a string 'City Center' as it should the first row to be fetched

Tags: mysql, laravel, database

My requirement is to fetch data from a table but it needs to have a specific row at first position which would be in the result for example I have list of towns but I want 'city center' to be at the top position when fetching result from towns table.

Comment: You can do it with JS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153254/javascript-sort-select-options

Comment: @EHFShahab thanks but this is not what I was asking for, I think you didn't read my question properly, I got it what I needed in and have posted it below, basically I was asking to sort by word in mysql

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question basically was asking to sort by word in mysql

```
SELECT id, name
    FROM
        towns
    ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN name LIKE 'City Center%' THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END;
```